# MongoDB array stays empy after POST

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If a preform a post request (per insomnia) the "games" array stays empty. Am I missing something?

## UPDATE: new error afer `array.push({})`

"errorValidationError: games.0.gameID: Path `gameID` is required., games.0.isGameActivated: Path `isGameActivated` is required., games.0.isStartTimeTBD: Path `isStartTimeTBD` is required., games.0.startDateEastern: Path `startDateEastern` is required., games.0.startTimeISO: Path `startTimeISO` is required., games.0.hTeam: Path `hTeam` is required., games.0.hTeamScore: Path `hTeamScore` is required., games.0.hTeamTricode: Path `hTeamTricode` is required., games.0.vTeam: Path `vTeam` is required., games.0.vTeamScore: Path `vTeamScore` is required., games.0.vTeamTricode: Path `vTeamTricode` is required."

[image]

Comment: have a look at the updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `save` on newGame object.
`new Game({ ... })` will only create an object of the model that you created. You need to call `save` method on the object to save it back to database.

`newGame.save()`

More info can be found [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html#constructing-documents)

#### EDIT AFTER THE UPDATE

I noticed that you provide _id field as well while constructing your object. If it is an update of an existing document that you intend to do then I highly recommend that you use one of `findAndUpdate` style of offering from mongoose. There are several methods that you could use to do so like `findByIdAndUpdate`, `findOneAndUpdate` or simply `update` with value of `upsert` set to true(if the document matching the criteria is not already present then it will be created when upsert=true).

Let me know how that goes.

Comment: Oh my bad, the sceenshot doesn't show it but I did call the save() method

Comment: This is just adding new games to MongoDB. To update these collection I'll use the methods u mentioned .Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You define your model with a property `games` and inside that property is all the information.

When you create your model, you didn't use the `games` property.

Try this:

```js
const newGame = new Game({_id});
newGame.games.push({ // your data here }); 
newGame.save();
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but now I keep getting valitadionErrors altough the JSON i'm submitting is correct.

Answer (score 0):

## GOT IT!

I so stupid... It needed to loop over the request first and then push it to an array! Here is the code:

```
// ADD GAMES
router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
    const _id = req.body._id;
    let games = [];
    req.body.games.forEach(game => {

        const gameID = game.gameID;
        const isStartTimeTBD = game.isStartTimeTBD;
        const isGameActivated = game.isGameActivated;
        const startTimeEastern = game.startDateEastern;
        const startDateEastern = game.startDateEastern;
        const startTimeISO = game.startTimeISO;
        const vTeam = game.vTeam;
        const vTeamTricode = game.vTeamTricode;
        const vTeamScore = game.vTeamScore;
        const hTeam = game.hTeam;
        const hTeamTricode = game.hTeamTricode;
        const hTeamScore = game.hTeamScore;

        games.push({
            gameID,
            isGameActivated,
            isStartTimeTBD,
            startDateEastern,
            startTimeEastern,
            startTimeISO,
            hTeam,
            hTeamScore,
            hTeamTricode,
            vTeam,
            vTeamScore,
            vTeamTricode,
        });
    });

    const newGame = new Game ({
        _id,
        games: games
    })

    newGame.save()
    .then(() => res.json('Game added cuz'))
    .catch(err => res.status(400).json('error' + err));

});
```